# How to use optimistic lock with hibernate when no fields changed

Tags: hibernate, versioning, optimistic-locking

I'm using a optimistic strategy when updating entities by setting `"<version />"` element in hbm.xml s. It works fine when I update a single entity. But this strategy fails when dealing with this scenario:

```
public class SalesPlan {
    //omitted fields
    private Resource resource;
    private DateRange dateRange;
}


public class Resource {
    //omitted fields
    private int version = 1;
}
```

and there is a constraint: A **Resource** should not have **SalesPlan** s with overlapped dateRange.For example:

Given there is a **Resource** named "Hippoom resort"

And it has a **SalesPlan**  ranging from Nov 1, 2013 to Nov 2, 2013

When I want to add a **SalesPlan** ranging from Nov 2, 2013 to Nov 2, 2013

Then It should fail for overlapped date range

I have to implement this in Java because database unique key does not work in this "range" case.The code looks like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public SalesPlan handle(CreateSalesPlanCommand command) {
    Resource resource = resourceRepository.findBy(command.getResourceId());
    SalesPlan salesPlan = //omitted init codes

    DuplicateSalesPlanSpecification spec = aDuplicateSpec();

    if (spec.isSatisfiedBy(salesPlan)) {
        throw new DuplicateSalesPlanException(salesPlan);
    }

    salesPlanRepository.store(salesPlan);
    resourceRepository.store(salesPlan.getResource());
    return salesPlan;
}
```

I fetch all existed **SalesPlan** s from the database in **DuplicateSalesPlanSpecification** to check if the new **SalesPlan** breaks the constraint.I want to update the **Resource** in the last step (check the version number in Resource) in case of concurrent operations. But I note there is no update sql because the Resource is not dirty.

——————Revised————————

```
select
    resource0_.RESOURCE_ID as RESOURCE1_0_0_,
    resource0_.version as version0_0_,
    //omitted columns
from
    T_IRS_RESOURCE resource0_ 
where
    resource0_.RESOURCE_ID=?


select
    this_.SALES_PLAN_ID as SALES1_1_0_,
    this_.version as version1_0_,
    this_.RESOURCE_ID as RESOURCE3_1_0_,
    this_.DATE_RANGE_START as DATE4_1_0_,
    this_.DATE_RANGE_END as DATE5_1_0_,
    //omitted columns
from
    T_IRS_SALES_PLAN this_ 
where
    this_.RESOURCE_ID=? 
order by
    this_.DATE_RANGE_START desc,
    this_.SALES_PLAN_ID desc


insert into T_IRS_SALES_PLAN//omitted columns


update T_IRS_RESOURCE set version = version + 1
where RESOURCE_ID = ?
and VERSION = ?            //this sql missed
```

While using optimistic strategy, the SalesPlan fetch sql could be stale if someone insert a new SalesPlan in another transaction without the last sql

```
|  the first transaction started               |
|                                              |  the second transaction started
|  select resource                             |
|                                              |  select resource 
|  select all salesplans                       |
|                                              |  select all salesplans
|  validate base on all committed salesplans   |
|                                              |  validate base on all committed salesplans
|  insert salesplan                            |
|                                              |  insert salesplan
|  update resource to check version            |
|                                              |  update resource to check version
|  commit txn                                  |
|                                              |  rolls back because version is dirty
```

——————Revised————————

The Hibernate version is 3.6.10.FINAL.Is there any possibilities I can fix this?

Comment: From your code I cannot see any changes you made to either the SalesPlan or Resource entity. So unless there is more code (then please post it) there is no reason to update because there are no changes.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear. I want to save the "SalesPlan" and check if the "Resource" is not modified by others. Please see the revised post content.

Comment: Why you aren't using HQL for this with constraints instead of trying to fix it in the entity?

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long : Sorry, I don't get it. Could you show me some example codes？

Comment: I want this update in case that someone else want to add a new SalesPlan concurrently. This will break the validation because most database can only read committed data.

Answer (score 0):

I find a interim solution. I add a boolean field on Resource like:

```
public class Resource {
    //omitted fields
    private int version = 1;

    private boolean dirty = false;

    public void alwaysMakeDirty() {
        this.dirty = !dirty;
    }
}
```

This field doesn't mean anything in the domain, but before I update the Resource, I can use alwaysMakeDirty() to fire the update sql.

I know it's quite tricky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try em.Lock (class, primaryKey, LockModeType) with

*LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC* - this one check the version in the end of transaction in the case of that someone changes it in the middle and eventually rolls back or *LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT* - this one always update and check the version in the end of transaction and rolling back if necessarily